# shotwell 0.12 shared library error

Tags: shotwell, shared-library

i installed [shotwell 0.12](http://blog.yorba.org/clinton/2012/03/shotwell-0-12-0-released.html) like so via its [official ppa](https://launchpad.net/~yorba/+archive/ppa)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yorba/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install shotwell
```

and when i tried to run it via dash it didn't start.
i then typed in the gnome-terminal "shotwell" I then got this error

```
error while loading shared libraries: libgexiv2.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

my question is how to get shotwell 0.12 up and running in ubuntu 11.10 amd64

Comment: This looks like a new bug, starting today. I use the same PPA and 64-bit 11.10. I can't open Shotwell at all.

Comment: do you also have [Darktable](http://www.darktable.org/) installed? I do, and get 'unmet dependencies' errors with that package when I try to reinstall the library.

Comment: Can you update Shotwell and test that it works again? If yes, you should accept one of the answers below. If not, update your question. Everything should work by now.

Comment: i updated shot-well and everything works great i accepted the answer of Adam dingle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just released Shotwell 0.12 yesterday, and unfortunately the 64-bit build failed on the Yorba PPA (though the 32-bit build worked fine).  We don't know why yet:

http://redmine.yorba.org/issues/4949

Investigating this now is our top priority.  I expect we'll have this worked out within a day or so.  Thanks for your patience!

Adam Dingle, Yorba Foundation

Answer (score 1):

From the terminal

Try installing libgexiv: `sudo apt-get install libgexiv*`

Comment: i got an error of the .dbg package the rest i installed still shotwell didn't work. this is the error for the .dbg package                                                            the following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libgexiv2-0-dbg: Depends: libgexiv2-0 (= 0.3.1-0ubuntu2) but 0.4.0-0oneiric1 will be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.        a have a dutch version of Ubuntu the error i translated with google translate.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a problem with Oneiric 64-bit.
https://launchpad.net/~yorba/+archive/ppa/+build/3323887

I also got the same error, tried to reinstall Shotwell and necessary libraries, including from scratch (+libraries), but without any luck.

Answer (score 1):

I removed libgexiv2-0: `sudo apt-get purge libgexiv2-0`

Then reinstalled shotwell: `sudo apt-get install shotwell`

And this solved my problem.

Comment: This worked for me too, on Ubuntu 12.10 using the yorba PPA.